# CsvHelper "HasHeaderRecord" get only? How to append without header?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

It seems in a recent (?) update the entire configuration class is read only and I cannot set `HasHeaderRecord` to true to allow proper appending.

How am I supposed to append without a header now? My last working implementation is below...

```
internal void Write(Record record) 
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(_filepath, true))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
        csv.WriteRecord(record);
        csv.NextRecord();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Create a `CsvConfiguration` and pass it to the `CsvWriter` constructor

Comment: Latest version doesn't seem to have a CsvConfiguration class

Comment: It does, but I think it's in another namespace

Comment: @Magnetron yes found it, thank you!

Comment: Example of [`csv.WriteHeader`](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/#writing-a-csv-file) is given on this page.

Answer (score 4):

You now have to pass a `CsvConfiguration` and set it there. Also, `CsvConfiguration` is in the `CsvHelper.Configuration` namespace.

```
CsvConfiguration config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    HasHeaderRecord = true
};
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(_filepath, true))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, config))
{                
    csv.WriteRecord(record);
    csv.NextRecord();
}
```